# leitura php get cardinaal

Tags: php

Boas quando mando o seguinte endereço o get não me está a ler o # alguem sabe porque

http://localhost:9090/tt.php?action=getclientes&utilizador=ws407105277&password=!DablyouS407#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua o # pelo código %23. Não é possível enviar esse caracter via get

Comment: e o + sabes como posso passar?

Comment: Dependendo da linguagem que estiver usando se for PHP você pode usar  a função urlencode http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php e ele transforma os seus caracteres especiais pra você.